# Problem with @resource and springcloud DiscoveryClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

There are four Implements for Interface DiscoveryClient
(org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;)

```
    @Resource
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    public void getServerPort(){
        List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstances = discoveryClient.getInstances("PROVIDER-PAYMENT");
        ......
    }
```

Why @Resource select EurekaDiscoveryClient instead of others?

Comment: Why are you using @Resource rather than @Autowired? A discovery client is not a resource. Also, please show your dependencies and versions

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: You should add them to the question, not as comments in the future. What other discovery client types do you have (since you didn't show any in the comments above)?